# How to open the input for a particular subject instead of opening all of them?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

In the code snippet below, I have a react component, currently I'm working on the CRUD functionality of this app. The problem I'm facing is I have an input below each subject data div. Upon clicking the edit button all the inputs get opened which I kind of expected. I only want to open the particular input for the data of which the edit button was clicked. Here's the code snippet:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import Navbar from '../../components/Navbar'
import './Exam.sass'
import officeSupplies from  '../../assets/office supplies-6010.svg'
import pencilToSquare from '../../assets/pencil-to-square.svg'
import trash from '../../assets/trash.svg'
import { useNavigate, useParams } from 'react-router-dom'
import axios from 'axios'

const Exam = () => {

const token = localStorage.getItem('token')

const [subjectName, setSubjectName] = useState('');
const [achievableScore, setAchievableScore] = useState(0);
const [obtainedScore, setObtainedScore] = useState(0);

const [title, setTitle] = useState('');
const [subjectData, setSubjectData] = useState([]);

const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

const { exam } = useParams()
const navigate = useNavigate()

const verify = () => {
    if (!token) navigate('/login')
}

const requestAddSubject = async e => {
    e.preventDefault()

    try {

        const floatAchievableScore = parseFloat(achievableScore)
        const floatObtainedScore = parseFloat(obtainedScore)

        await axios.post(`http://localhost:5000/exams/${exam}/addsubject`, {
            subjectName,
            achievableScore: floatAchievableScore,
            obtainedScore: floatObtainedScore
        })
        window.location.reload()
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}

const requestSubjectData = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true)
    try {
        axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = localStorage.getItem('token')
        const res = await axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/exams/${exam}`)

        setSubjectData(res.data.subjects)
        setTitle(res.data.examName)
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    setIsLoading(false)
}

useEffect(() => {
    verify()
}, [])

useEffect(() => {
    requestSubjectData()
}, [])

return (
<>
    <div className="exam">
        <Navbar suffix={`Dashboard > ${title}`} />
        <div className="exam__title">
            <h1 className="exam__title-text">{title}</h1>
        </div>
        {!isLoading && subjectData.length == 0 &&
        <>
            <div className="exam__image">
                <img src={officeSupplies} alt="" className="exam__image-img" />
            </div>
            <div className="exam__empty">
                <h1 className="exam__empty-title">No Subjects added yet!</h1>
            </div>
        </>
        }

        {!isLoading && subjectData && subjectData.length > 0 && subjectData.map(subject => 
        <React.Fragment key={subject._id}>
            <div className="dashboard__subject__data">
                <h3 className="dashboard__subject__name">{subject.subjectName}</h3>
                <h3 className="dashboard__subject__percent">{subject.percentage}%</h3>
                <h3 className="dashboard__subject__total">{`${subject.obtainedScore}/${subject.achievableScore}`}</h3>

                <div className="dashboard__subject-options">
                    <button onClick={() => setOpen(true)} className="dashboard__subject-option btn"><img src={pencilToSquare} alt="" className="dashboard__subject-option-img" /></button>
                    <button className="dashboard__subject-option btn"><img src={trash} alt="" className="dashboard__subject-option-img" /></button>
                </div>
            </div>

            {open &&
            <div className="exam__subject-inputs">
                <input onChange={e => setSubjectName(e.target.value)} type="text" className="exam__subject-input grey-input" placeholder='Subject Name' />
                <input onChange={e => setAchievableScore(e.target.value)} type="number" className="exam__subject-input grey-input" placeholder='Achivable Score' />
                <input onChange={e => setObtainedScore(e.target.value)} type="number" className="exam__subject-input grey-input" placeholder='Obtained Score' />
                <button onClick={requestAddSubject} className="exam__subject-submit btn">Update</button>
            </div>
            }
            <hr />
        </React.Fragment>
        )}

        {!isLoading &&
        <div className="exam__subject-inputs">
            <input onChange={e => setSubjectName(e.target.value)} type="text" className="exam__subject-input grey-input" placeholder='Subject Name' />
            <input onChange={e => setAchievableScore(e.target.value)} type="number" className="exam__subject-input grey-input" placeholder='Achivable Score' />
            <input onChange={e => setObtainedScore(e.target.value)} type="number" className="exam__subject-input grey-input" placeholder='Obtained Score' />
            <button onClick={requestAddSubject} className="exam__subject-submit btn">Add Subject</button>
        </div>
        }

        {isLoading &&
            <div className="dashboard__error-message-container">
                <h1 className="dashboard__error-message">Loading...</h1>
            </div>
        }

        <div className="exam__danger-zone">
            <div className="exam__name-edit-container">
                <div className="exam__name-edit">
                    <input type="text" className="exam__name-edit-input grey-input" placeholder='Change    Name' />
                </div>

                <button className='exam__edit-button btn'><img src={pencilToSquare} alt="" className="exam__edit-img" /></button>
            </div>

            <div className="exam__delete">
                <button className="exam__delete-button">Delete Exam</button>
            </div>
        </div>            
    </div>
</>
 )
}

export default Exam
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behaviour as you only have boolean state (open). How does it know which subject's edit panel to show.

You need to have state which can store something that will identify which subject is currently selected.

You can do something like below

Add a state to store selected subject

```
const [openSubject, setOpenSubject] = useState('');
```

Then on the edit button you need to set that state with subject id.

```
<button onClick={() => setOpenSubject(subject._id)} className="dashboard__subject-option btn"><img src={pencilToSquare} alt="" className="dashboard__subject-option-img" /></button>
```

Finally you can compare to decide which subject's edit form should be shown.

```
{openSubject === subject._id && (
    <div className="exam__subject-inputs">
       <input onChange={e => setSubjectName(e.target.value)} type="text" className="exam__subject-input grey-input" placeholder='Subject Name' />
       <input onChange={e => setAchievableScore(e.target.value)} type="number" className="exam__subject-input grey-input" placeholder='Achivable Score' />
       <input onChange={e => setObtainedScore(e.target.value)} type="number" className="exam__subject-input grey-input" placeholder='Obtained Score' />
       <button onClick={requestAddSubject} className="exam__subject-submit btn">Update</button>
    </div>
)
```